# Why the memory barriers in Volatile.Read() and Volatile.Write()?

Tags: .net, volatile, memory-barriers

Here is what the MSDN documentation has to say about `System.Threading.Volatile.Read()`:

> On systems that require it, inserts a memory barrier that prevents the processor from reordering memory operations as follows: If a read or write appears after this method in the code, the processor cannot move it before this method.

And for `Volatile.Write()`:

> On systems that require it, inserts a memory barrier that prevents the processor from reordering memory operations as follows: If a read or write appears before this method in the code, the processor cannot move it after this method.

My understanding is that a "volatile" read, by definition, always gets the current value of a memory location, and a volatile write is immediately committed to memory. So volatile read/write semantics avoid unexpected results due to your processor relying on cached data. But a volatile read or write is only a single memory access operation, and doesn't have anything to do with prior or subsequent memory accesses, no?

The memory fences that are used in `Volatile.Read()` and `Volatile.Write()` might be useful in certain scenarios, but their functionality seems to be outside the scope of a volatile read or write. Why are they included in those method implementations? If a programmer wants to ensure that two writes are committed to memory in a specific order, why not simply make the programmer use two calls to `Volatile.Write()`?

Comment: It is often the case that you want a write sequenced after "all writes that took place before it", and it's not practical or even possible to replace all writes with `Volatile.Write`. For example, `s = String.Concat(x, y); Volatile.Write(ref ready, true);` There is no way to make the `String.Concat` use Volatile.Write`.